# Keycloak-gatekeeper: 'aud' claim and 'client_id' do not match

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

What is the correct way to set the `aud` claim to avoid the error below?

```
unable to verify the id token   {"error": "oidc: JWT claims invalid: invalid claims, 'aud' claim and 'client_id' do not match, aud=account, client_id=webapp"}
```

I kinda worked around this error message by hardcoding `aud` claim to be the same as my `client_id`. Is there any better way?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak-proxy:
    image: "keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper"
    environment:
     - PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:3000
     - PROXY_DISCOVERY_URL=http://keycloak.example.com:8181/auth/realms/realmcom
     - PROXY_CLIENT_ID=webapp
     - PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET=0b57186c-e939-48ff-aa17-cfd3e361f65e
     - PROXY_UPSTREAM_URL=http://test-server:8000
    ports:
      - "8282:3000"
    command:
      - "--verbose"
      - "--enable-refresh-tokens=true"
      - "--enable-default-deny=true"
      - "--resources=uri=/*"
      - "--enable-session-cookies=true"
      - "--encryption-key=AgXa7xRcoClDEU0ZDSH4X0XhL5Qy2Z2j"
  test-server:
    image: "test-server"
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

With recent keycloak version 4.6.0 the client id is apparently no longer automatically added to the audience field 'aud' of the access token. 
Therefore even though the login succeeds the client rejects the user.
To fix this you need to configure the audience for your clients (compare doc [2]).

### Configure audience in Keycloak

- Add realm or configure existing
- Add client my-app or use existing
- Goto to the newly added "Client Scopes" menu [1]

  - Add Client scope 'good-service'
  - Within the settings of the 'good-service' goto Mappers tab

    - Create Protocol Mapper 'my-app-audience'

      - Name: my-app-audience
      - Choose Mapper type: Audience
      - Included Client Audience: my-app
      - Add to access token: on
- Configure client my-app in the "Clients" menu

  - Client Scopes tab in my-app settings
  - Add available client scopes "good-service" to assigned default client scopes

If you have more than one client repeat the steps for the other clients as well and add the good-service scope.
The intention behind this is to isolate client access. The issued access token will only be valid for the intended audience.
This is thoroughly described in Keycloak's documentation [1,2].

#### Links to recent master version of keycloak documentation:

- [1] https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/clients/client-scopes.adoc
- [2] https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/audience.adoc

#### Links with git tag:

- [1] https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/f490e1fba7445542c2db0b4202647330ddcdae53/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/audience.adoc
- [2] https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/5e340356e76a8ef917ef3bfc2e548915f527d093/server_admin/topics/clients/client-scopes.adoc

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error, it looks like gatekeeper is still checking for client_id, even though I have confirmed that the token has the scope of the good-service.

Comment: Works for me. Actually, the steps can be simpler. Client Scopes are shared mappers and roles. Here we can just add a mapper for my client.

1. edit my client
2. open the `mapper` tab
3. Create Protocol Mapper 'my-app-audience'.  The value is just the same as this reply.

Comment: When I add the mapper, my `aud` becomes a list of [`account`, `my-custom-client`], and the audience validation still fails.

Comment: @StealthRabbi you need to remove the [audience resolve](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/clients/oidc/con-audience.adoc#automatically-add-audience) in Client Scopes -> roles -> Mappers

Comment: The links to "master" are broken because the main branch has been renamed to "main".

Comment: @MaxR.  I did this part "you need to remove the audience resolve in Client Scopes -> roles -> Mappers" but still see the Client Id name in audience. Is there any way I can see the name of my Client Scope?

Answer (score 16):

This is due to a bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8954

There are [two](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12444401/config.png) [workarounds](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-8954?focusedCommentId=13695636&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13695636) described in the bug report, both of which appear to do basically the same thing as the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627747/712765) but can be applied to the Client Scope `role`, so you don't have to apply them to every client individually.

Answer (score 6):

If, like me, you want to automate the keycloak config, you can use kcadm

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh \
        create clients/d3170ee6-7778-413b-8f41-31479bdb2166/protocol-mappers/models -r your-realm \
        -s name=audience-mapping \
        -s protocol=openid-connect \
        -s protocolMapper=oidc-audience-mapper \
        -s config.\"included.client.audience\"="your-audience" \
        -s config.\"access.token.claim\"="true" \
        -s config.\"id.token.claim\"="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its works to me:

In my SecurityConfiguration class:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        
        return source;
    }
```