# What is the purpose of redirection-url in keycloak gatekeeper?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper, louketo-proxy

I'm trying to set up Keycloak Gatekeeper as a reverse proxy in front of my service, but I don't know what the purpose is of the `redirection-url`. I figured I could just put Gatekeeper in front of my service, without my service needing to know anything about the authn/z. This doesn't seem possible if it needs a callback endpoint.

I was able to deploy the Keycloak Server, Keycloak Gatekeeper, and a simple node service (all deployed locally in docker containers). With a bit of hacking to my hosts file, I was able to send a request to Gatekeeper, which properly authenticated me and redirected me back to my node service. However, my node service needed to add a `/oauth/callback` endpoint, since Gatekeeper adds that suffix to whatever is specified in the `redirection-url`.

Here is what my Gatekeeper config looks like:

```
discovery-url: http://keycloak-server:8080/auth/realms/master
client-id: proxy-node-server
client-secret: abcabcab-abca-abca-abca-abcabcabcabc
listen: ':3001'
enable-refresh-tokens: true
redirection-url: http://node-server:3000
encryption-key: <ENCRYPTION_KEY>
upstream-url: http://node-server:3000
resources:
- uri: /*
secure-cookie: false
```

I expect to be able to put Gatekeeper in front of a service that has no knowledge of authentication, authorization, OIDC, etc, but with the `redirection-url` that doesn't seem possible.

Is there any way to get Gatekeeper to do authnz when needed and just act as a simple proxy when the user is properly authenticated? Or is there something I don't understand where this is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatekeeper help:

```
--redirection-url      value redirection url for the oauth callback url, defaults to host header is absent [$PROXY_REDIRECTION_URL]
```

You will need to use `redirection-url`, only when gatekeeper sits behind loadbalancer or another reverse proxy. That `redirection-url` is required for Open ID Connect flow. When user is authenticated, then `redirect-url` is not applied of course.

Comment: Found an issue that was the [missing client id in the aud for the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550321/keycloak-gatekeeper-aud-claim-and-client-id-do-not-match). Still just seeing a blank page, and now getting a 400 instead of a 403, but making progress. Will update if I find anything else.

Comment: Turns out express doesn't like ~something about the request~ the size of the headers of the request and considers it malformed (400). I was able to get it working with an echo server. Thanks