# Keycloak javascript adapter to call protected rest api

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, keycloak

I have a pure java script application without servlet or any other backend framework.
I have created a jsp file:
keycloakClientHome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/keycloak.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/keycloak-call.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <script>
        parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin)
 </script>
 <a href="#" id="keycloakCallId">Call Protected Agent</a>
 <h1 id="results">Result:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

keycloak-call.js
/**
 * 
 */

```
     var keycloak = Keycloak();
    keycloak.init({
         onLoad: 'login-required',}).success(function(authenticated) {
        alert(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failed to initialize');
    });

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#keycloakCallId").click(function(e){
        keycloak.updateToken(30).success(function() {
            //Call to protected rest API
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   beforeSend: function(request) {
                       console.log("Token value"+keycloak.token);
                        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+keycloak.token);
                       /*request.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic "+encodeBase64('rachel' + ":" + 'rachel'));*/
                      },
                   url: "http://localhost:8086/dbaasrest/login",
                   contentType: "json",
                   success: function(data) {
                       console.log("response:" + data);
                       $("#results").append(data);
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(' Error in processing!');

                   }
               });
        }).error(function() {
            alert('Failed to refresh token');
        });

     });
});
```

When I hit from the browser http://localhost:8086/KeycloakJSClient/keycloakClientHome.jsp..gets redirected to keycloak login page and on successful login it shows the jsp content.

[image: Home jsp page]

When I click the link and call the protected REST API, deployed on same server.
[image: error in browser console]

When I hit the spring rest api, it do not ask for authentication anymore, since already authenticated.
Javascript and spring rest api are two different applications both deployed on tomcat port-8086.
But when I hit the link from authenticated jsp page and it shows 401-Unauthorized.Can anyone tell me, what might be the reason.

The client Accesstype in keycloak is public

Keycloak.json file used in REST API and javscript application

```
{
  "realm": "dev",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "employee-service",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "enable-cors": true
}
```

Keycloak Client settings screenshots
[image: Keycloak client setup]

[image: Client_role]

[image: role and user mapping]

Comment: you have multiple commented lines in `beforeSend` function. May be you have forgotten to uncomment it. Cause as I see right now you do not send this token on server

Comment: I have uncommented the code and keycloak.token in Authorization header.Still the same 401 error is comming. I have updated my code with keycloak.json file and keycloak client settings.@Aleksei can you please check once

Comment: @Aleksei : It worked out. I was missing audience configuration.Created client scope with mapper of Audience type and it worked out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550321/keycloak-gatekeeper-aud-claim-and-client-id-do-not-match/53627747#53627747   Followed this one