# keycloak - define audience for jwt

Tags: docker, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using jwt protection for my projects and here I stand up via "KeyCloak" docker.
Since I define in "Audience" in the applications I make, I want to define it on keycloak, but it cannot be defined somehow.

I made the definition as in the address below, but the audience does not appear in the jwt token at all.
The address below did not help me.

Can you help me if there is a document or example about how I can add this?

[Keycloak-gatekeeper: 'aud' claim and 'client_id' do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550321/keycloak-gatekeeper-aud-claim-and-client-id-do-not-match)

**Client Scope**

[image]

**Mappers**

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the "audience" I specified does not appear in the marked field. How can I provide this?
[image]

Comment: The Protocol mapper should work: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_audience_hardcoded

Comment: I did as requested, but it is not added to the "aud" field as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your audience in Mapper > Create Protocol Mapper > Included Custom Audience

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your client scope to your client or use the pre-existing client scope that was auto-created.

[image]