# get auth tokens without using cognito-specific boto APIs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, idp

I am currently using AWS Cognito for user authentication. However, I have plans to make AuthN IDP agnostic. For example, I want to be able to replace Cognito with some other identity provider later.

Currently, I use `boto3` cognito API to get `idToken` like below. How can I write a non-cognito specific implementation to get idTokens so that when the provider changes, I won't be relying on cognito? I want to use some generic python OAuth APIs to obtain idToken for the user. How can I do that?

```
    cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    response_tokens = cognito_client.initiate_auth(
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': uname,
            'PASSWORD': pwd
        },
        ClientId=OAUTH_AUDIENCE
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get ID token from Cognito you need to call a specific API. And if you want to switch to other IDP later, then you need to use other API provided by that IDP. So, APIs are specific to the IDP.

Hence, as at this moment you want token from Cognito, you need to use AWS APIs.

That said, in case by "different IDP" you mean to say "configuring different IDP with Cognito" then I would like to add that, OAuth 2.0 flow can not be made using CLI or SDKs. Cause, OAuth 2.0 flow is a browser based flow and to login with different IDP you need to use browser.