# Validate and parse Auth0 JWT token in python

Tags: jwt, auth0, jwk

When someone logs in on my website through Auth0, I get a JWT token from Auth0. This token tells me the UID of the person and allows me to make API calls from the frontend to the backend where I can validate the JWT token to make sure the request comes from a logged in user.

On https://jwt.io you can paste any JWT token and it'll parse it and verify the signature.

Does anyone know how I can do this in python?

Auth0 doesn't give me the private key of the JWT token, so I can't use `jwt.decode()`.

Instead I need to somehow parse the JWT token with its public key, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it in python.

This is the JWT token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImZneF9xWEJVNWt0ZzZXSlNLdTJIdiJ9.eyJuaWNrbmFtZSI6ImpvaG5fbWFyayIsIm5hbWUiOiJqb2huX21hcmtAb3V0bG9vay5jb20iLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zLmdyYXZhdGFyLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvNTMxZmJlZjcxN2I1NzVmYjU3MGJlYzcxNTBlOWQ4MTA_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.NQBQPoEj6wzYzclrQzXAWh124gyg_Nf1UYZR4lAuqHZ-fdFycrBMA0Y0dBSvQ-WI7YZOMAPjCRK0nuxKzj9kMQ0c-3finCgsl411tX5tvaX_Khe116le_eyBV28aQQLjqT0zvLaSgIYaJqcgshQ1bYvJp8UXPf8GkMWCD89pnqYPwexx9nsWjrnikInLY9oSbWYN1zA7DxwhygI_JeQc6Cvu6pl1xq8m_WZaCMSOJS2umyl_7vfA84cDX1Zz8aVWEOMinnbmR48sY79cEiIMplcYJA3QH4yFEawSWbzWnVUcv9VCgCJ7fCbqikF86fz2TrWYrI6eATJoVHOXDNDKwA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you won't get the private key. But the private key is only used to sign the token. You only need the public key to verify the token.
The `jwt.decode()`function is called decode, but also verifies the token, that's why the key is needed.

The [documenation](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets) tells you, where to find your JWKS (JSON Web Key Set) with the public key.

> Auth0 exposes a JWKS endpoint for each tenant, which is found at https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json. This endpoint will contain the JWK used to verify all Auth0-issued JWTs for this tenant.

The issuer URL is also encoded in the token in the `iss` claim (you can see it when you inspect your token on https://jwt.io):

in your case:
https://dev-n8ghykyo.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json

You can then retrieve the key from that endpoint with the code shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548480/7329832)